# Changing cell value from number (100) into 100% using R Markdown

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here's how my current data set looks like

```
df # I'm just typing it as I'm using R Markdown fake data
```

```
A tibble:5 x 3
UID <dbl> question <fctr> response <dbl> 
1   Q1  38      
2   Q1  30      
3   Q1  64      
4   Q1  97      
5   Q1  100
```

I'd like change my data frame into the following format

```
A tibble: 5 x 3
UID <dbl> question <fctr> response <dbl> 
1   Q1  38%     
2   Q1  30%     
3   Q1  64%     
4   Q1  97%     
5   Q1  100%
```

I've used `df$response<-sub("^",".",df$response)` then realized this will make anything that's `100` into `.1` which will make it `10%` instead of `100%`.

Would it be better to just add `%` at the end of my each cell value or is there another way to address this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may paste i.e. `df$response <- paste0(df$response, "%")`, but the column type will be character

Comment: That actually may work @akrun as ultimately, I'm doing this to feed into Tableau. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @akrun It did work! Thank you so much, I just had to manually change once I feed the data into Tableau from String to Numeric.

Comment: You know this was so dumb, I could've divided my var into 100. I figured out:
`df$response <- df$response/100` works better